# How to use the data from reading a file

Tags: c#

Write a program that reads a set of exam scores from a text file.

Compute the followings:

1. The total number of students in the class
2. The percentage of students for each letter grade
3. The range of scores for the entire class
4. The class average score

Honestly guys I'm very lost, I know how to open the file and read what's in it but no idea how to use it. I realize the code I have doesn't do me any good for what I'm trying to do. just not sure where to go?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strStudent;

            StreamReader studentsFile;
            studentsFile = File.OpenText("Exam_scores.txt");


            for (int count = 1; count < 5; count++)
            {                
                //Read data                
                strStudent = studentsFile.ReadLine();                

                //Display records                
                studentsListBox.Items.Add(strStudent);

            }            
            // close the connection            
            studentsFile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content of `Exam_scores` File:

```
96
53
92
30
97
76
78
45
81
49
91
42
67
40
43
53
80
85
77
92
47
45
72
36
83
36
34
71  
96
56
87
86  
87
98
96
97
55
44
53
93
67
38
82
64
96
```

Comment: How is each letter grade defined from the score?

Comment: @ja72 

        90-100% = A
        80-89% = B
        70-79% = C
        60-69% = D
        59% and below = F

Answer (score 2):

To read the file straight to a string array :

```
var scores = File.ReadAllLines("Exam_scores.txt");
```

Now, you have a string array but to perform calculations you will need an int array:

```
var intScores = scores.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

So far so good, now you can start with calculations :

```
var totalNumberOfStudents = intScores.Count();
var minScore = intScores.Min();
var maxScore = intScores.Max();
var avgScore = intScores.Average();
```

I hope this is enough for you to get the idea.

Comment: The `.Average()` for a list of integers does not round the number, which in should in real life. For example average of 63.7144 => 64.

Comment: To round the number, you can try [Math.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8). Just like `double d1 = Math.Round(63.7144, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the scores to a listbox, I would convert the string to an int and add it to a List which makes your calculations easy.  Also, you are hard coding the length of the file to 5 in your for loop which wont work.  You could replace your for loop with this:

```
List<int> scores = new List<int>();
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("Exam_scores.txt"))
{
    string s = "";
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int score = int.Parse(s);
        scores.Add(score);
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following for you calculations.

```
int totalStudents = scores.Count;
var percentStudentsWithA = scores.Count(x => x >= 90) / scores.Count;
var percentStudentsWithB = scores.Count(x => x >= 80 && x < 90) / scores.Count;
....
var lowestRange = scores.Min();
var highestRange = scores.Max();
var average = (decimal)scores.Sum() / (decimal)scores.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code sample below deals with all aspects of data reading and handling, and none of the aspects of displaying the results into UI elements, or as strings.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Declare a list of integers for the scores
        var scores = new List<int>();

        // Here you open the text file and read each line
        var fs = File.OpenText("Exam_scores.txt");
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = fs.ReadLine();
            // Ignore empty lines
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
            {
                continue;
            }
            // Try to convert a line into a number
            if (int.TryParse(line, out int score))
            {
                // Add number to scores
                scores.Add(score);
            }
        }
        fs.Close();


        // Now work with the list
        int studentCount = scores.Count;

        // create groups for scores A=90..100, B=80..89, C=70..79, D=60..69, F=0..59
        var scoreDistribution = new Dictionary<char, float>
        {
            { 'A', (float)scores.Count((score) => score>=90)/ studentCount },
            { 'B', (float)scores.Count((score) => score>=80 && score<90)/ studentCount },
            { 'C', (float)scores.Count((score) => score>=70 && score<80)/ studentCount },
            { 'D', (float)scores.Count((score) => score>=60 && score<70)/ studentCount },
            { 'F', (float)scores.Count((score) => score<60)/ studentCount }
        };

        // example on how to read a value from the dictionary.
        float percent_of_A = scoreDistribution['A'];

        // range is defined from the minimum and maximum
        int range = scores.Max() - scores.Min();

        // average can needs rounding so it is calculated using
        // floats. Convert the sum into a float, divide by the 
        // count, call the rounding function and convert into integer.
        int average = (int)Math.Round((float)scores.Sum()/studentCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you have to do? What information do you have?

- You have a file that contains scores - one per line.
- Each score represents a student => *count of lines = number of students*
- to get the range find the lowest and the highest score:
  *scoreRange = highestScore - lowestScore*
- average score is the sum of all scores divided by the number of students
- calculate grade from each score and count each grade. Then calculate for each grade category:
  *numberOfGradeX / numberOfStudents * 100 = percentageOfGradeX*

---

```
var scores = new List<int>();

// Read each line from the file...
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("Exam_scores.txt"))
{
  // ...and convert the string to int for calculation
  if (int.TryParse(line, out int score))
  {
    // Collect the scores
    scores.Add(score);
  }
}

/* TODO */
int numberOfStudents = GetStudentCount(scores);
int scoreRange = GetScoreRange(scores);
double scoreAverage = GetScoreAverage(scores);
double gradeAPercentage = GetGradeAPercentage(scores);
...
double gradeFPercentage = GetGradeFPercentage(scores);
```

You can use `Enumerable` [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.8#methods) to simplify some calculations (e.g. `scores.Min()`).